# php non blocking timeout on workers

Tags: php

I'm creating a chat bot, I have php workers picking up the outgoing messages from a message queue. I am getting an array of messages from the payload (from the queue). I want to send out the messages with a lag in order to imitate the 'typing'.

```
while (true) {
    $messages = pickMsgFromQueue();
    sendMessagesWithDelay($messages);
}

function sendMessagesWithDelay(array $messages) {
    if (empty($messages)) {
        return;
    }

    sendMessage(shift($messages));
    sleep(1); // This will take 99.9 % of script time obviously
    sendMessagesWithDelay($messages);
}

function sendMessage($message) {
    // some curl call;
}
```

The problem is, the bot worker will be sitting on the `sleep()` function for most of the time and the only solution I have right now is to have a lot of workers running at the same time so a new message on the queue gets picked up as soon as possible.

Is there a good way to solve this problem without multithreading or starting another php process?

cheers!

Comment: Long story short, please take a look at [amp project](http://amphp.org/). You need async non blocking, you're not using it. It's possible, and quite similar to what node.js does. No need to swap out the language or infrastructure. @Tschallacka it's obvious you're not aware of all the tools available to us PHP guys so I believe your comment is completely wrong. Nothing bad with being a fanboy though, but it just sucks to spread false knowledge.

Comment: The article mentioned in @Tschallacka 's comment is pretty old. Agreed that there were a lot of issues with memory leaks etc, but that was 4-5 years back, not true anymore!

Comment: @Mjh I came across the amp project but I couldn't figure out how that would help me, could you show me pseudo code on how that would work inside the while loop of a worker?

Comment: On the index page of the project I linked, there's `timer.php` example. Basically you'd get rid of your `while` loop and replace it with `Amp\run(function() { });`. All your code would go into the mentioned closure. If you want to delay sending a message to particular user for X seconds, I *think* (did not test, can't do it right now), you'd use `Pause` class from the mentioned project.